# How to catch ONLY Errors not warning in markers Eclipse JAVA

Tags: java, compiler-errors, eclipse-plugin

So i am developing a eclipse plugin

and i want to catch only the Errors found in PROBLEM VIEW when Building a project.

This is my code for it

```
markers2 = resource2.findMarkers(IMarker.PROBLEM, true, IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE);
                if (markers2 != null) {
                    for (IMarker m : markers2) {
                        System.out.println("Message: " + m.getAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE));
                        System.out.println("Line Number: " + m.getAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER));
```

But this code also detects the WARNINGS found. How to limit this to only ERRORS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Severity attribute of a problem marker tells you if it is an error, warning or just info.

```java
 IMarker marker = ....

 int sev = marker.getAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, IMarker.SEVERITY_INFO);
```

`sev` will be one of

- `IMarker.SEVERITY_ERROR`
- `IMarker.SEVERITY_WARNING`
- `IMarker.SEVERITY_INFO`

So

```
IMarker [] markers2 = resource2.findMarkers(IMarker.PROBLEM, true, IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE);
if (markers2 != null) {
   for (IMarker m : markers2) {
     int sev = m.getAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, IMarker.SEVERITY_INFO);
     if (sev == IMarker.SEVERITY_ERROR) {
        System.out.println("Message: " + m.getAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE));
        System.out.println("Line Number: " + m.getAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER));
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: IMarker[] markers2 =markers2 = resource2.findMarkers(IMarker.PROBLEM, true, IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE); if this is my Imarker[], what should i put in here?  IMarker marker = ....

Comment: In your `for` loop - where you have each individual marker  `m` in your case.